# Show that the degree of a minimal polynomial of f is greater than or equal to the degree of f.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I am stuck on this problem in linear algebra:

Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space with $dim(V) = n$, f a linear transformation, and $A$ a transformation matrix of $f$.

There exists $v$ in $V$ so that $v$, $f(v), \dots, f^{k-1}(v)$ are linearly independent. Show that the degree of the minimal polynomial $m_f$ of $f$ is greater than or equal to $k$.

I know that if $v$, $f(v), \dots, f^{k-1}(v)$ are linearly independent, then $f^{k}(v)$ is linearly dependent. If we let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $f$, then $(f - \lambda * id)^{k}(v) = 0$. This means the minimal polynomial $m_f$ divides it, but I'm not sure how to prove that it must be degree $k$.

I wish I could say I've gotten something more than this done, but I am having a hard time.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $m_f<k$. There is a polynomial $p(x)=x^{m_f}+a_{m_f-1}x^{m_f-1}+\cdots+a_0$ such that $p(A)=0$ (where $a_i\in K$ for each $0\le i\le m_f-1$).

That is, for any $v\in V$ we have $f^{m_f}(v)+a_{m_f-1}f^{m_f-1}(v)+\cdots+a_0v=0\in V$. In particular, there is a nontrivial linear relation between $\{v,\dots,f^{m_f}(v)\}\subseteq\{v,\dots,f^{k-1}(v)\}$. But this contradicts $v,\dots,f^{k-1}(v)$ being linearly independent.